# knockout: how to hide a paragraph tag using visible data bind observable?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a paragraph tag which i want to hide conditionally. I am unable to hide it.

This is demo code:
[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qtm9446o/2/)

This is what i have tried- made one observable variable and assig:

```
var viewSellerBtnVisible = ko.observable(true);
viewSellerBtnVisible(false);
```

viewSellerBtnVisible(false) is conditional in the original code but even then its not getting hidden.

What should i do to hide this paragraph tag?

Answer (score 0):

Working demo:

```js
var viewSellerBtnVisible = ko.observable(true);
ko.applyBindings({ viewSellerBtnVisible: viewSellerBtnVisible }, document.getElementById("txtRecommendationHeading"));
viewSellerBtnVisible(false);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<h3  class="">People also liked...</h3>
<p id="txtRecommendationHeading" data-bind="visible: viewSellerBtnVisible" class="font11">View seller details in <strong>one click</strong></p>
```

In your code:

```
ko.applyBindings(viewSellerBtnVisible, document.getElementById("txtRecommendationHeading"));
var viewSellerBtnVisible = ko.observable(true);
viewSellerBtnVisible(false);
```

The model should be a JavaScript object, mapping names to values. `viewSellerBtnVisible` in your code is a value; Knockout cannot know what its name would be just from that.

You also apply bindings using a variable name that has not yet been defined. At the point where you `applyBindings`, `viewSellerBtnVisible` is not even an observable, it is `undefined`. Since parameters are passed by object sharing, and not by reference, the binding does not become an observable later. You need to have a proper sequence of instructions.

Finally, your Fiddle doesn't have Knockout loaded. When playing with Fiddle, you should add libraries you're using under "External resources".